# C++ runtime convert gif to png

Tags: c++, png, gif

Although I have found a lot about converting PNG to GIF for various languages and platforms, interestingly there are very few things to convert GIF to PNG with C++. I am rendering GIF images by using [mimeTeX](http://www.forkosh.com/mimetex.html) and want to draw them to my PDF by using [libharu](http://libharu.org/). The problem is that neither mimeTeX can render PNG, nor libharu can draw GIF. I know really limited things about both formats (just some elementary things I read from official PNG website and Wikipedia) and thus cannot convert GIF to PNG. I am very sorry that I cannot show you what I have tried because I could not find a start point. Please also note that all images will be created at runtime. I can use any kind of library that will work on Windows 7; and since my code is already excessively complex, I really do not want to make it even more complex. If a simple trick exist for this specific job, it will be highly appreciated. Thanks for that.

Comment: You could break the problem down by converting to "raw data" as an intermediate step.  Both those image formats convey a *height*, *width*, and a *collection of colors*, one for each pixel.  And practically all image converters support some kind of "raw data" representation.  Have you tried that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ImageMagick is the way to go; there's even a C++ library: http://www.imagemagick.org/script/magick++.php

Comment: First of all thank you, now I'm using Imagemagick (specifically, using convert program); but the problem is that when I convert GIFs to PNGs libharu cannot draw those images sometimes a "draw error occures" (I don't know why it occures) and sometimes image looks extremely ugly that looks like a chaos. Do you know why those things happen?

Comment: @Equalitiesofpolynomials If you load the PNGs in any other viewer do they look ok?  If not, are the original GIFs ok?

Comment: I actually solved problem a while ago. When I am converting images I have written: "convert image.gif image.png" but this solved my problem: "convert image.gif PNG8:image.png"

Comment: @Equalitiesofpolynomials Ah, you needed to keep it as an 8-bit image. Good to hear you have it working. Perhaps your display code requires it to stay as 8-bit data?

Comment: Yes apparently my display code requires 8-bit data, it is working for me now. Thank you for your help.